# Populating Sub documents according to userid

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on MEAN application.I am trying to manage separate data for each user logged in. I need to populate sub collection under my main collection **user**.

user.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
password: String,
role: String,
pwd_token: String
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
 exports.default = User;
```

cat.js

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
breed: String,
colour: String
});
var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', catSchema);
exports.default = Cat;
```

How to populate sub collection with my user according to the userid?

Comment: from `CAT` model you want to populate?

Comment: Bro, I need cat under my user collection

Comment: `Cat` will be inside You user collection and , while you will query from user you want that `cat ` to be populated . ?

Comment: exactly bro thats what i needed

Comment: added an answer, check it once

Answer (score 0):

so, say, there is a field in **User** [`User.js`] Model named, `cat_id` that conntains Cat `_id` . Which  is reference of `Cat` Model.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
    var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
    password: String,
    role: String,
    pwd_token: String,
    cat_id:{
      type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:"Cat" //Reference Of Cat Model otf Type ObjectId
    }
    });
    var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
     exports.default = User;
```

Now, if while You making query From Cat, Just Do `populate("user_id")` to Populate That User Doc Related to That `user_id`

Sample Query:
This query will Give You all `User`  Docs . with populating related `Cat` doc inside it.

`User.find({}).populate("cat_id").exec()`

Here is the [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) For `.populate()`

Comment: I have done this var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
    password: String,
    role: String,
    pwd_token: String,
    cat_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Cat" //Reference Of Cat Model otf Type ObjectId
    }
}); var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
User.find({}).populate("cat_id").exec();
exports.default = User;                                                                                   but its not populating the  cat

Comment: make sure, `cat_id` is matching any  `_id`  of  `Cat` collection Docs.

Comment: You mean user_id should should be in Cat?

Comment: no, `cat_id` [in `User` ] should be a valid `_id` from `Cat` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164222/discussion-between-chris-and-saikat-chakrabortty).